# Punctuation and listing two elements (when one of them is a list)

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, lists

> Wolf is a referee who provides scholarly peer review to the Israel
>   Science Foundation and with the following journals:Journal of Public Economics, Journal of the Association of Environmental and Resource
>   Economists, Journal of Environmental Economics and Management, Journal of Economic
>   Behavior and Organization, The Energy Journal, American Journal of Agricultural
>   Economics, Environmental and Resource Economics, Resource and Energy Economics,
>   Energy Economics, Energy Policy, Canadian Journal of Economics, Journal of Economics,
>   Southern Economic Journal, Ecological Economics, Journal of Public Economic Theory.

I want to rewrite the above sentence so that the Israel Science Foudation is placed at the end of the sentence. The objective of this rewriting is that Wolf's publications in journals has been more noteworthy than that with the Israel Science Foundation.
The trouble is that the Israel Science Foundation is not a journal, otherwise I would have listed it after the colon and after
American Journal of Agricultural Economics.  The research I did includes New Hart's Rules but I have not found anything helpfull.

Is the following attempt correct: ?

> Wolf is a referee who provides scholarly peer review to the following
>   journals:Journal of Public Economics, Journal of the Association of
>   Environmental and Resource Economists, Journal of Environmental
>   Economics and Management, Journal of Economic Behavior and
>   Organization, The Energy Journal, American Journal of Agricultural
>   Economics, Environmental and Resource Economics, Resource and Energy
>   Economics, Energy Economics, Energy Policy, Canadian Journal of
>   Economics, Journal of Economics, Southern Economic Journal, Ecological
>   Economics, Journal of Public Economic Theory.; as well as to the
>   Israel Science Foundation.

How would you rewrite the sentence (preferably into one sentence)?

Comment: Simple fix: refer to "the following publications" instead of "the following journals."

Comment: If "Israel Science Foundation" isn't a journal, then you can't include it in a list of journals appearing after a colon that specifically indicates that what follows are journals.  Moreover, a semicolon would be inappropriate since the previously list items were not separated by semicolons, what follows the semicolon isn't actually included in the list of journals, and what follows the semicolon isn't a main clause.  If you want to say that he provides scholarly peer review to the Israel Science Foundation afterwards instead of before, then you'd say that in a new sentence.

Comment: @Robusto - From what I gather, the Israel Science Foundation is also not a publication.  Rather, it appears to be a foundation.  Wolf provides peer review to the foundation itself, presumably members of it, while he also provides peer review via those various publications, those publications being some kind of vehicle for that activity rather than the actual recipient.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: Then ... "as well as to publications of the Israel Science Foundation" would be my solution.

Comment: See also: [writing.se] Good Luck.

Comment: What's the problem with the natural: "... Journal of Public Economic Theory, as well as to the Israel Science Foundation." There's no ambiguity so long as you have the preposition *to* in there.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that many of the journal-type items have the word "journal" in them.  Why not delete "journals" and just list all the things:

> Wolf [is a referee who] provides scholarly peer review to Journal of Public Economics, Journal of the Association of Environmental and Resource Economists, Journal of Environmental Economics and Management, Journal of Economic Behavior and Organization, The Energy Journal, American Journal of Agricultural Economics, Environmental and Resource Economics, Resource and Energy Economics, Energy Economics, Energy Policy, Canadian Journal of Economics, Journal of Economics, Southern Economic Journal, Ecological Economics, Journal of Public Economic Theory, and the Israel Science Foundation.

If you need this long list of journal names to be once sentence, I think you'll have to rely on a bit of inference to not lose your reader. If I was reading the sentence for the first time, I think I would assume that all list items are journals while reading it, since many have "Journal" in the title. When I then encounter the last item, the Israeli Science Foundation, I would certainly recognize that as an organization that is not a journal.

Minor note: I put "is a referee who" in brackets, because I suspect it's redundant with "provides scholarly peer review". In other words, if providing scholarly peer review makes Wolf a referee, then "is a referee who" is dispensable.

Comment: mRotten: It's not that simple. I abridged the list for the sake of brevity. I already edited the question. The list of journals now includes the ones that do not have the word "journal" in the title.

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska: It's not critical that they all have the word "journal" in them, so it can still be that simple.

Comment: That was not the question, though.

Comment: mRotten: Your answer seems to be a viable solution. That said, the biography of Woolf is going to be an encyclopaedia article, and that's why I would rather introduce the word journal in the sentence, for it to be more informative for a lay man.

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska Why did you request one sentence then?

Comment: @mRotten I want it (only preferably) in one sentence, but what is a must is to clearly list which entities are journals and which are not. I wanted one sentence in order to avoid repetitions. Perhaps I am wrong expecting that you can construct such a sentence without it being awkward.

Answer (score -2):

Possibly:

> Wolf is a referee who provides scholarly peer review *for* numerous academic journals, including Journal of . . . , as well as the Israel Science Foundation.

You could put "including . . . in parentheses.

But, a question:  Wolf is a referee. Does he also write book reviews?  Publish articles? I'd guess that what he's reviewing for the Israel Science Foundation are proposals for research rather than articles to be published, which is what "referee" implies.

I think you could get rid of "is a referee who", since he's providing scholarly peer review for numerous journals as well as the Israel Science Foundation.

Comment: I have no more knowledge with respect to his refereeing than what I've already adduced.